# Deploying of Node Express app - errors due to ESM import

Tags: node-modules, es6-modules

I created an app with Node and Express using ESM module import.
I deployed my app to a shared linux server with CPanel and I am getting errors like this:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072
    throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, true);
    ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/ferexaho/notes_app/app.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /home/ferexaho/notes_app/app.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at startApplication (/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:48:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:16:1) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
```

What I understand is that somewhere, but I don't know where, there's a require() which is not allowed since I am using ESM imports.
I am sure it's not in my code, since I am using only imports.
How do I spot which module is causing this error?